# issues interating jboss eap6 with ActiveMQ 5.9

Tags: activemq-classic, jboss-eap-6

> I have the activeMQ server running in the jvm at tcp://localhost:61616

then i place the activemq-rar-5.9.0.redhat-610379 unzipped

> adaptor

in the

> \runtimes\jboss-eap\modules\system\layers\base\org\apache\activemq\main

in the adaptor i have the Meta-INF

in the jboss EAP6 , standalone.xml i have specified the

But when i start the server ... i get the below error

**

> 12:05:39,910 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 40) JBAS014612: Operation ("add") failed
>   - address: ([
>       ("subsystem" => "resource-adapters"),
>       ("resource-adapter" => "activemq-rar.rar") ]) - failure description: "JBAS010473: Failed to load module for RA
>   [org.apache.activemq]"

**

Answer (score 2):

Your question is missing some information, but in reviewing what you have typed it sounds like you are missing the module.xml that needs to go in your module directory (\runtimes\jboss-eap\modules\system\layers\base\org\apache\activemq\main)

For ActiveMQ RAR version 5.9 a module.xml would look like the following

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.apache.activemq" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="."/>
    <resource-root path="activemq-broker-5.9.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="activemq-client-5.9.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="activemq-jms-pool-5.9.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="activemq-kahadb-store-5.9.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="activemq-openwire-legacy-5.9.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="activemq-pool-5.9.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="activemq-protobuf-1.1.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="activemq-ra-5.9.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="activemq-spring-5.9.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="aopalliance-1.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="commons-pool-1.6.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="commons-logging-1.1.3.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="hawtbuf-1.9.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-core-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-expression-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="xbean-spring-3.14.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <exports>
    <exclude path="org/springframework/**"/>
    <exclude path="org/apache/xbean/**"/>
    <exclude path="org/apache/commons/**"/>
    <exclude path="org/aopalliance/**"/>
    <exclude path="org/fusesource/**"/>
  </exports>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="org.slf4j"/>
    <module name="javax.resource.api"/>
    <module name="javax.jms.api"/>
    <module name="javax.management.j2ee.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

Also, you should really not create custom modules under \modules\system\layers\base\ as this is used by JBoss and could be modified during patches and new releases.  You are best to either create your own layer or simply create you module directly under the /modules folder.

As previous answer has noted, especially in a standalone setup it might be easier to just directly deploy the RAR instead.

Answer (score 1):

I am having trouble reading your question.  In general, I would recommend deploying the A-MQ JCA rar file via either the command line CLI or via the web UI and not as a module.  Just go to the web UI, find the "Deployments" page and deploy the A-MQ JCA.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I followed the tutorial http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/ironjacamar/configuring-a-resource-adapter-for-activemq-on-jbosswildfly.

I'm using a JBoss EAP 6.3.x and in my case the problem was in reference to the `META-INF/ra.xml` file. If I comment out the `config-property` below the note

```
<!-- NOTE disable the following property if you do not wish to deploy an embedded broker -->
```

I got the same error like you. If I removed the `config-property` the problem was solved and it's working as expected.