# deploy WMQ resource adapter as a module in JBoss EAP 6

Tags: jboss, ibm-mq, jboss-eap-6

I'm trying to simplify the provisioning of JBoss EAP 6 applications by adding common components to the base EAP 6 installation directory (e.g. ojdbc driver).

For the WMQ JCA resource adapter, I have everything working just fine if I put the '*wmq.jmsra.rar*' archive in the '*deployments*' folder. I just need to configure the *resource-adapters* section of the *standalone.xml* file according to the official documentation.

Now, is it possible to create a JBoss module and include it via the '*global-modules*' section? I tried creating a module *wmq.ra* with resource-root *wmq.jmsra.rar*, but the module won't load.

Comment: Can you provide the module definition and resulting logs? If there's no useful information in logs, try setting different logging level.

Comment: logs are very limited, even in DEBUG. The only useful error codes I get are: `JBAS014612: Operation ("add") failed` and `JBAS010473: Failed to load module for RA [wmq.ra]`. I'm investigating on those now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may have found the answer i was looking for. I ran into post about the similar issue for Active MQ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28848338/issues-interating-jboss-eap6-with-activemq-5-9) and [here](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/ironjacamar/configuring-a-resource-adapter-for-activemq-on-jbosswildfly). I followed the same canvas for WMQ:

- unpack the *wmq.jmsra.rar* in your module directory (e.g. *modules/wmq/jmsra/main/*)
- create a *module.xml* descriptor for you module

  - this one worked for me with WMQ 7.5.0.3. I had problems when some of the dependencies were missing

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="wmq.jmsra">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="."/>
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.mq.commonservices.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.mq.connector.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.mq.headers.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.mq.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.mq.jms.admin.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.mq.pcf.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.mqjms.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.msg.client.jms.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.msg.client.matchspace.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.msg.client.provider.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.msg.client.ref.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="dhbcore.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.resource.api"/>
        <module name="javax.jms.api"/>
        <module name="javax.management.j2ee.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

- import your module the usual way in *standalone.xml*

I didn't fully validate this solution in production like environment, I'll update if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [EAP6 and WebSphere MQ Integration](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/Deploy_the_WebSphere_MQ_Resource_Adapter.html) document for installing and configuring the resource adapter.

Comment: Thanks, but that was already done. As I state in the question, I have things working with the resource adapter deployed in 'deployments', I want to have the resource adapter load as a module.